# How to visualize the steps of an algorithm

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

How can I delay execution of an algorithm to visually display the results of each iteration in the algorithm? When I try to update the height of the objects in the code below, it only shows the final result. How can I display what happened at each step?

```
namespace BubbleSortRappresentazione_grafica
{     
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int[] v;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Random rnd = new Random();

            v = new int[10];
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                v[j] = rnd.Next(0, 100);   
            }
            _0.Height = v[0] + 20;
            _1.Height = v[1] + 20;
            _2.Height = v[2] + 20;
            _3.Height = v[3] + 20;
            _4.Height = v[4] + 20;
            _5.Height = v[5] + 20;
            _6.Height = v[6] + 20;
            _7.Height = v[7] + 20;
            _8.Height = v[8] + 20;
            _9.Height = v[9] + 20;   
        }    

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // algoritmo ordinamento    

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {                       
                    if (v[j] > v[i])
                    {   
                        int tmp = v[j];
                        v[j] = v[i];
                        v[i] = tmp;

                        _0.Height = v[0] + 20;
                        _0.Content = v[0];
                        _1.Height = v[1] + 20;
                        _1.Content = v[1] ;
                        _2.Height = v[2] + 20;
                        _2.Content = v[2];
                        _3.Height = v[3] + 20;
                        _3.Content = v[3] ;
                        _4.Height = v[4] + 20;
                        _4.Content = v[4];
                        _5.Height = v[5] + 20;
                        _5.Content = v[5];
                        _6.Height = v[6] + 20;
                        _6.Content = v[6];
                        _7.Height = v[7] + 20;
                        _7.Content = v[7];
                        _8.Height = v[8] + 20;
                        _8.Content = v[8];
                        _9.Height = v[9] + 20;
                        _9.Content = v[9];

                        Thread.Sleep(100);   
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to view the components change content and height "on real time" ?

Comment: Modifications are only repercuted to the graphical interface when the method is done, not during, since these calls block the UI thread. Use a `BackgroundWorker` to see the changes in real time.

Comment: when i do the loop, for example i want to change the size of buttons in for, it change the size but graphically not , it shows the changes  at the end of the loop and not during it , so i'd like to find something that make the changes graphics during the cycle

Comment: yes i want to see changes in Real times

Comment: I don't understand how everyone thinks it is unclear what is being asked, but if it is reopened, I will post a full working example for the poster.

Comment: [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you're looking for. (put it after the sleep.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard DoEvents in a WPF application?  What are you, some kind of *monster*?  This isn't VB6!  I'm so ashamed for you right now.  OP is doing so much so fast, I doubt even if he will see much of anything, in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you're really  looking for is [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {                       
        if (v[j] > v[i])
        {   
            //...
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }   
    }
}
```

This will cause that whatever visual changes you're making inside the loop will be applied in each iteration. You can also consider removing the `.Sleep()`, as I'm not sure how useful it is for you.